# pulling data from wp_postmeta in own CMS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have tried many ways to get this data and i believe this is the best and last solution to my problem.

I have imported wp_posts and wp_postmeta into my own built php mysql cms, and now i am trying to pull data from wp_postmeta i am so close to getting to the finish line on this but am stuck on the last tiny bit.

```html
<?php $querystr = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id} AND 'meta_key' LIKE '_story_url' ";
                       $select_postmeta = mysqli_query($connection, $querystr);
                  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_postmeta)) {
                    
                    
                    $story_url = $row['_story_url'];
                    
                    
                }
?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated,

Problem - Cannot seem to pull the data out of the wp_postmeta the query i have supplied to pull the data seems to not work

the page i am working on is post.php which has a get request of the post_id that is working perfectly pulling data from wp_posts but getting the postmeta to pull out of the database that is related to that post is a mind bender

Comment: Stuck on what?  whats the error/question here?  Just a guess "LIKE '_story_url'" - is that the right wildcards you want to use there?  no %?

Comment: _story_url is the meta_key and the value is a link i believe my code to pull out the meta_key and value with the same post_id as the post is wrong

Comment: you have meta_key in quotes like it's a value not a field name.  Outside of that, could you edit your question to clearly state what your problem is?

Comment: ok updated tried to explain further

Comment: AND 'meta_key' LIKE '_story_url'  will always return false, no?    should that be    AND meta_key LIKE '_story_url'?    (no quotes around meta_key)

Comment: tried that mate i get this error which is the same error with the quotes

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: story_url in C:\wamp64\www\cms\post.php on line 77 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0010249760{main}( )...\post.php:0 " target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Visit Site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$story_url = $row['_story_url'];
```

should be

```
$story_url = $row['meta_value'];
```

_story_url is the name of the meta field, not the name of the database field.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply i have tried your changes and it still will not pull the data out i get a notice 

Notice: Undefined variable: story_url in C:\wamp64\www\cms\post.php on line 76 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0000248880{main}( )...\post.php

Comment: I assume that you've gone with changing `'meta_key' LIKE '_story_url'` to `meta_key LIKE '_story_url'` before doing this as was previously suggested by Twelfth in a comment above. Have you? What does `var_export($row)` in the while loop output?

Comment: <?php $querystr = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id} AND meta_key LIKE '_story_url' ";
                       $select_postmeta = mysqli_query($connection, $querystr);
                  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_postmeta)) {
                    
                    
                    $story_url = $row['meta_value'];
                    
                   var_export($row);
                }
?>

Blank showing nothing

Comment: if i remove post_id = {$the_post_id} AND , it shows all the urls for _story_url for every post in a array

Comment: i tried :

'$querystr = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_story_url' AND post_id = '{$the_post_id}' ";'

Comment: Are you certain $the_post_id is set to the correct post ID? Print it, and run the query manually via phpmyadmin/mysql cli, does that work?

Comment: i have this if(isset($_GET['p_id'])){
                    
                $the_post_id = $_GET['p_id'];
                    
                 }

Comment: i echo the post id and got 18829

Comment: Can you run the query in phpmyadmin and get results? Are you sure about _story_url being the exact name of the postmeta field? That SQL is pretty simple, there must be something fundamentally amiss if the while loop is never entered.

Comment: The fields are all correct if I remove the post url query all the story urls show from 2500 posts